# Basic example of structural induction : " for any term $t$, substituting an even number for all variables in $t$ yields an even number"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, induction

***Source*** : http://blog.cambridgecoaching.com/an-introduction-to-proofs-the-structure-of-induction ; ***§ " Structural induction"***

---

This is a question about a basic  example of structural induction .

The property to be proved is that : if all the variables of a term $t$ are replaced by an even number, then the term is even; let this property be called ***$P$***

Note. Here, a term is defined recursively by

(1) any variable is a term

(2) if $t_1$ and $t_2$ are terms, so are $(t_1 + t_2)$ and $(t_1\times t_2)$.

The proof goes like this

> ***Base step*** ($t$ is a variable): Since $t$ is a variable $x$ and that variable
> is even, then so is $t$.
>
> ***Induction step $(t = (s + r))$***:

> Assume, as the induction hypothesis,
> that $P(s)$ is true and $P(r)$ is also true.  We will show that $P((s + r))$
> is true.

> Assume every variable in $(s + r)$ is even.  Then every
> variable in $s$ and $r$ is even (since these variables are exactly the
> variables in $t$).   By the induction hypothesis, both $s$ and $r$ are even.
> Therefore $(s + r)$ is even.  Therefore P((s + r)) holds.

My question : I understand that $s$ is even and $r$ is even hold in virtue of the induction hypothesis. But how can one infer from this that $(s + r)$ is even? ***Isn't this assuming what has to be proved ( namely that the sum of any two even numbers is even)?***

***Original text*** :

Structural induction

Let's try to prove something about our terms.

Theorem: Given terms (using only the operations + and *) if every variable is replaced with an even number, then the result is even.

Again, you may say this is obvious.  But why?  You may say:

Addition and multiplication of even numbers preserves even-ness.

You are correct, but once again there is a hidden "and so on" in your argument.

even + even = even

even * even = even

(even * even) + even = even + even = even

(even + even) * even = even * even = even

and so on

Once again induction can come to the rescue.  Since terms can be defined inductively with a base case and and induction case, we can follow the same induction template as with the natural numbers.

Proof: Let P(t) denote the property: if all variables in the term t are replaced with even numbers then the term t is even.  We show that P(t) holds for all terms by induction on the term t.

Base step (t is a variable): Since t is a variable x and that variable is even, then so is t.

Induction step (t = (s + r)): Assume, as the induction hypothesis, that P(s) is true and P(r) is also true.  We will show that P((s + r)) is true.  Assume every variable in (s + r) is even.  Then every variable in s and r is even (since these variables are exactly the variables in t).   By the induction hypothesis, both s and r are even.  Therefore (s + r) is even.  Therefore P((s + r)) holds.

Induction step (t = (s * r)): Assume, as the induction hypothesis, that P(s) is true and P(r) is also true.  We will show that P((s * r)) is true.  Assume every variable in (s * r) is even.  Then every variable in s and r is even (since these variables are exactly the variables in t).   By the induction hypothesis, both s and r are even.  Therefore (s * r) is even. Therefore P((s * r)) holds.

By induction, P(t) holds for all terms t. QED

Comment: You asked: “Isn't this assuming what has to be proved ( namely that the sum of any two even numbers is even)?”.  No, this isn't what was to be proved.  What was to be proved is about the behavior of _terms_: if all the variables in a term are replaced with even numbers, the result is even.   The much simpler statement that "the sum of two even numbers is even" is taken as already known.